# Linux - Trouble Shooting Web Page

Tags: linux, webserver, html

I was asked this question last night by a friend and I am stumped. So I thought I would ask here.

The question is:

**How would you trouble shoot a web page that is not loading on a linux web server?**

Comment: What message does the web server give you? What's the error code?

Comment: If you are having trouble shooting the web page, perhaps you should not shoot the web page!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your Network Interface Configuration card first:

Open a terminal, then type: `ifconfig`.

Verify the interface you are using has an ip assigned. e.g:

An active interface looks like this:

```
wlan0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:06:25:09:6A:D7
         inet addr:216.10.119.243  Bcast:216.10.119.255 <--notice ip here 
         UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
         RX packets:2924 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
         TX packets:2295 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
         collisions:0 txqueuelen:100
         RX bytes:180948 (176.7 Kb)  TX bytes:166521 (162.6 Kb)
         Interrupt:10 Memory:c88b5000-c88b6000
```

And a shutdown interface:

```
wlan0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:06:25:09:6A:D7
        BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
        RX packets:2924 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
        TX packets:2287 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
        collisions:0 txqueuelen:100
        RX bytes:180948 (176.7 Kb)  TX bytes:166377 (162.4 Kb)
        Interrupt:10 Memory:c88b5000-c88b6000
```

If you believe the server is able to connect to internet, send and receive some packages from it to test if it is able to transfer data properly through the internet:

From another computer, in the terminal type the command ping followed by your server's ip (the one you got with the command ifconfig), e.g:

```
ping -c 10 216.10.119.243
```

the `-c 10` part is for only sending 10 packets (that way you dont have to stop it with ctrl C).

After that, you can use the `curl` utility. It acts like a text based Web browser in which you can select to see either the header or complete body of a Web page's HTML code displayed on your screen.

A good start is to use the curl command with the -I flag to view just the Web page's header and HTTP status code. If you dont use -I then you will see all the we page's html code displayed on the screen.

So, type curl -I and then the ip of your server, for example

```
curl -I 216.10.119.243
```

You can use the `wget` command to download a Web site's Web pages, including the entire directory structure of the Web site, to a local directory of yours.

If you activate timestamping (-N), you view not only the HTML content of the Web site's index page in your local directory, but also the download speed, file size and the start and stop times for the download. You could use it like this:

```
wget -N 216.10.119.243
```

If you want to see the amount of traffic in and out of your server, use:

```
netstat -an
```

Lastly use

```
traceroute -I 216.10.119.243
```

to verify the route path and transit times of packets between your machine and the server you are troubleshooting.

That should do it. Hope it helps.

Comment: Just so you know, there's a toolbar option on the editor that looks like this: `{}` which formats your code (indents it four spaces). You can also use backticks ``` to cause code to be code-formatted in-line. Not sure if you know that or not, but I've added it to your post so you can see how it looks. +1 for all the suggestions by the way.

Comment: @Mercury I only edited the answer to make it a little more readable. @AndresR is the author, to whom your thanks should be directed!!